# Access A Value in Wunderground API

Tags: swift, wunderground

I am trying to incorporate Wunderground into my current project. I have looked at several api tutorials, but I can't seem to figure out how to access a certain part of the API. For example, this is sort of what the API looks like:

```
{
   "response": {
   "version":"0.1",
   "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
   "features": {
      "history": 1
   }
   }
    ,
"history": {
    "date": {
    "pretty": "August 9, 2015",
    "year": "2015",
    "mon": "08",
    "mday": "09",
    "hour": "12",
    "min": "00",
    "tzname": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
```

Let's say I wanted to return only the hour from the API. How would I do that?

Comment: Also, I **do not** want to have to use SwiftyJSON, because it has adverse effects on my project.

Comment: Curious:  what sort of adverse effects?

Comment: I get a segmentation error 11

Comment: Also, what have you tried?  You should be able to grab whatever part of the JSON you want once Wunderground returns the data...  Is the posted JSON what is returning from the API?  Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to parse JSON without frameworks:

```
typealias JSONdic = [String: AnyObject]

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: nsUrl), queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (_, data, _) -> Void in
    if let data = data, json = data as? JSONdic, history = json["history"] as? JSONdic, hour = history["hour"] as? String {
    println(hour)
}
```

Comment: But Swift does not recognize "json"

Comment: json is the name of variable, it's the data you got from Alamofire or NSURLConnection in closure.

Comment: I don't have either of those. Could you explain NSURLConnection? I'm completely new to APIs and JSON and have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @ButtonMasterBot expanded the example.